# React: экспорт нескольких классов из одного файла

Tags: reactjs, классы, typescript, react-native, export

Подскажите как разобраться со следующей ситуацией:

1. есть класс, описывающий данные (некоторое хранилище) - `BaseStorage`
2. есть класс, отнаследованный от `React.Component` и работающий с указанных хранилищем - `Manager`

Оба находятся в одном файле `manager.tsx`.
В основном нужен только `Manager`, поэтому я сделал классический экспорт `export default Manager`, но для typescript желательно указывать для переменных определённый тип (типа `store: BaseStorage = []`) вместо `any`.

Когда попытался сделать экспорт двух классов типа

```
export {
    BaseStorage,
    Manager
}
```

Полезли ошибки

Посему такой вопрос:

1. как сделать так, чтобы можно было использовать в нужных файлах только `BaseStorage`
2. не правильнее архитектурно такие вещи разделять на 2 отдельных файла и использовать из по мере надобности?

Comment: может лучше забабахать интерфейс, его экспортировать и от него имплементировать BaseStorage?

Comment: но никто не мешает тебе написать `export class BaseStorage` и `import Manager, {BaseStorage} from 'manager.tsx'`

Comment: @nörbörnën, а на счёт интерфейса поясни PLZ - что ты имел в виду и какие преимущества?